# Emacs, tramp, plink problem on XP

Tags: emacs, windows-xp, tramp, plink

The target machine is running Ububtu server 8.04.
Here's the tramp output:

```
tramp: Opening connection for nungu@ip.ip.ip.ip using nil...<br>
tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell<br>
tramp: Waiting 60s for prompt from remote shell<br>
tramp: Sending password<br>
tramp: Found remote shell prompt.<br>
tramp: Initializing remote shell<br>
Loading time-date...done<br>
tramp: Waiting 30s for remote `/bin/sh' to come up...<br>
tramp: Setting up remote shell environment

apply: Couldn't `stty -inlcr -echo kill '^U'', see buffer `*tramp/plink nungu@ip.ip.ip.ip*'
```

**edit, verbose buffer contains this at the end:**

```
# Waiting 30s for remote `/bin/sh' to come up...
exec env 'ENV=' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=$ ' /bin/sh
$ exec env 'ENV=' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=$ ' /bin/sh
$ 
# Setting up remote shell environment
$ stty -inlcr -echo kill '^U'
stty -inlcr -echo kill '^U'

$ $ $ [[Regexp `\(^[^#$%>
]*[#$%>] *\|^[^#$%>
]*[#$%>] *\(\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z] *\)*\)\'' not found in 30 secs]]
```

The command:
`stty -inlcr -echo kill '^U'`
`-inclr` turns off "translate newline to carriage return"
`-echo`  turns off "echo input characters"
`kill '^U'` sets '^U' to erase the current line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem; and a fix

Working: NTEmacs-22.1 - Tramp Version: 2.0.55

Failing: NTEmacs-22.3.1 - Tramp Version: 2.0.58-pre

See comment - neither 2.0.* release worked on emacs-22.3.1

Upgraded to tramp 2.1.14 - emacs 22/3/1 works great

Recommend you try upgrading from [Savannah](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/tramp).

Note: I didn't configure properly just deleted the existing tramp el and elc files from listp/net; and dropped the ones from the downloaded tar in - you need to modify trampver.el.in to build a meaningful lisp file - but it's not exactly rocket science

Comment: Downgraded the 22.3 emacs version to tramp 2.0.55 - same problem.
Upgraded the 22.1.1 emacs version to tramp 2.0.58-pre - still works

Looks like an emacs regression

Comment: thanks, I upgraded to 23 and it's working like a charm. Better than all that head scratching.

Answer (score 1):

*see buffer tramp/plink nungu@ip.ip.ip.ip'*

Well, what's in that buffer?

**edit** thanks for adding the buffer output.

The 'stty' command is trying to configure the terminal that TRAMP is going to use to access the remote system. What happens if you SSH directly to the system and try to run the command? (Use the same args TRAMP is using...)

Comment: Try bumping up the verbosity level of tramp by setting 'tramp-verbose' to 8 or 10 (output of 10 is described as "huge", so try 8 first). This should show you more info about what tramp is doing.

Comment: That's verbosity set to 10, I'm guessing it's trying to get the directory structure in those blank commands, but can't be sure.

Comment: For some reason that regex isn't matching but I'll be swelped if I can figure out why. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the technologies that you're talking about, but if Genehack says that your "regex isn't matching," then you need to test with a simpler Regex, or simplify your solution in some other way until you figure out the piece of the puzzle that does not work. You know, "it works with this simple regex, but not with this more complex one" or "it's not the regex at all, since NO regex works"...

Componentize, simplify, and bracket the problem, if  you will...

I realize this is obvious, general advice, but it's Sunday morning...

Comment: The regex is part of the tramp output, so tramp is calling that regex, not me, and I assume it's the command that failed, or the last command that worked.

Comment: Right, but I guess my question would still be, if there's any way to do it... is there any way to do just a PART of the command you're trying to run... even if it gives an impartial result, at least you could LOCATE the problem (and then solve it some other way, perhaps).

Comment: Or looking at this command (stty -inlcr -echo kill '^U'), could you try some other variations which you're NOT really interested in. Maybe there's something funky about control U or whatever.

Comment: It's the standard start up sequence for opening a file, any file, remotely in emacs using tramp. So, bar digging into the tramp code and changing the way it works, no dice.